# PDF reader that allows user to alternate between reading on PC and on Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, pdf, windows

I have to read a lot of PDF files and am wondering whether there is an app out there that allows me to alternate between reading on Windows PC and on Macbook Air.  I am thinking about an app that syncs all the notes and markups between devices and opens with the last page I read.  Could anyone please help?

Comment: Google Play Books will sync PDFs and show you the last page viewed, but It does not look like you can make notes on them. Also, it's an in-browser app. Evernote will allow you to make notes and other marks —paid version— but I don't think it syncs your last viewed page between devices...

Answer (score 1):

[Papers App](http://www.papersapp.com) does most of that. It is used for academic papers and can be synced via DropBox, including all notes and annotations. It does not keep track of your last read spot though.